# Can someone please explain how address(uint160(bytes20(b))) works differently than address(uint160(uint256(b)))?

Tags: solidity

Please explain how `address(uint160(bytes20(b)))` works differently than `address(uint160(uint256(b)))` when converting a type that uses a larger byte size then `address`, for example `bytes32`, then the `address` is truncated.

[Link](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#address): https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#address

Comment: What is `b`? a number, bytes, or ...?

Comment: @Alireza number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when converting a type that uses a larger byte size then `address`

Well, the behavior of these two methods depends on that type, for example:

- For `uint256 b`, they both return the same result, which is the 160 least-significant bits of `b`
- But for `bytes32 b`, the first method returns the 160 most-significant bits of `b`

---

Testing method (Truffle 4.x):

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract MyContract {
    function func1(bytes32 b) public pure returns (address) {
        return address(uint160(bytes20(b)));
    }
    function func2(bytes32 b) public pure returns (address) {
        return address(uint160(uint256(b)));
    }
    function func3(uint256 b) public pure returns (address) {
        return address(uint160(bytes20(b)));
    }
    function func4(uint256 b) public pure returns (address) {
        return address(uint160(uint256(b)));
    }
}

contract("MyContract", accounts => {
    const b = "0x8888888877777777666666665555555544444444333333332222222211111111";
    it("test", async () => {
        const myContract = await artifacts.require("MyContract").new();
        console.log(await myContract.func1(b));
        console.log(await myContract.func2(b));
        console.log(await myContract.func3(b));
        console.log(await myContract.func4(b));
    });
});
```

Note that some would argue that `func1` and `func2` have essentially received a different input **value** than `func3` and `func4`, hence the difference is in the input value rather than the method.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is:

```
bytes20(some_bytes32_value)
```

is capturing top (left) 20 bytes, while:

```
uint160(uint256(some_bytes32_value))
```

Is capturing lowest (right) 20 bytes.